# How to get a wpf-element as bitmap without using the RenderTargetBitmap? (or faster than using the RenderTargetBitmap?)

Tags: c#, wpf, video, bitmap, render

I need to get a canvas as bitmap in real-time (1920x1080 50FPS) , But the speed of the `RenderTargetBitmap.Render(Visual)`  is too low.(and it causes blocking UI)

(I've used multithread and `BitmapCache`  , but had no effect)

How to get a wpf element as bitmap faster than using the `RenderTargetBitmap`?

Comment: Maybe this [answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32538767/4377809) can help you with your issue

Comment: @Il Vic Thanks , Seems to be a good solution. I'll try it.